# Proper translation of Epicaricacy?

Tags: traducción

What is the proper translation of the word "[Epicaricacy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epicaricacy)"? Or is it one of those complex words that only have a meaning in the original language?

I found the translations "alegría maligna", "satisfacción malévola " and "epicaricacía". The latter one is, of course, what one would think as the proper translation but the [RAE does not identify it](http://www.rae.es/search/node/epicaricac%C3%ADa).

Comment: It's not an English word either. See the usage notes in the wiktionary, the discussion, the citations. It's not present in other English dictionaries either.

Answer (score 6):

The word *epicaricacy* is basically a supposed Greek-derived version of the German *schadenfreude* which is the word we actually use in English.

The German term is likewise used in Spanish — imported as femenine — along with the pure Spanish word *regodeo* from the verb *regodearse*. Quoth the DRAE:

> **regodearse** 3. prnl. coloq. Complacerse maliciosamente con un percance, apuro, etc., que le ocurre a otra persona.

Comment: Cuantos idiomas conoces?

Comment: Aparte de que traducir entre varios idiomas es una mala práctica, pues se pierde el significado, la palabra regodearse al Inglés es gloat.

Comment: @EmilioGort cuatro: inglés, castellano, asturiano y portugués.

Comment: Otra cosa, regodeo tiene dos significados (según la RAE), y  su significado depende del contexto, no como epicaricacy, cuyo significado en invariable.

Comment: @syrux No creo que pierda ningún sentido.  La traducción estándar de *schadenfreude* al español es *regodeo*.  *epicaricacy* es simplemente un supuesto intento de hacer más anglófona una palabra alemana (con la impresionante ironía de por integrar solo elementos griegos acabar con un resultado totalmente opaco para los anglohablantes).  El hecho de que *se pueda* traducir la palabra *regodearse* al inglés como *gloat* no contraindica el uso de *regodeo* (que con su significado de *efecto de regodearse* es imposible usar *gloat* en inglés como equivalente) para otras palabras (psuedo)inglesas.

Comment: @guifa, como usted menciona "schadenfreude al español es regodeo", la traducción que usted hace es de el aleman al español, no del inglés al español) como la pregunta lo requiere: "What is the proper translation of the word "Epicaricacy"?". Aparte, como mencione en mi comentario anterior, regodearse tiene DOS significados (completamente distintos), y su traducción del alemán estará determinada según el contexto.

Comment: @syrux Muy bien, entonces ¿resúltate mala práctica usar *play* para traducir *tocar*, *jugar*, *engañar*, *desempeñar*, *actuar* o *exploitar* (entre otras) ya que la palabra *play* tiene varios significados no tan específicos?  No me lo creo ni por un instante.  La traducción más común de *schadenfreude* es *regodeo*, por lo tanto, la traducción más adecuada de *epicaricacy* también es *regodeo*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16734/discussion-between-syrux-and-guifa).

Comment: Yo opino tambien que aunque "regodearse" implica no solo sentir alegria o satisfaccion por el mal ajeno, sino deleitarse en general con algo, saboreando la experiecia, es una traduccion bastante acertada. Independientemente de si queremos traducir del aleman o del ingles (que ya sabemos que no siempre es posible traducir todo literalemnte) la preguna busca una palabra en espaniol para "alegrase del mal ajeno" y "regodearse" lo capta muy bien.

Answer (score 1):

As a native Spanish speaker, I would say that somebody "se alegra del mal ajeno" but would never say "alegría maligna" nor "satisfacción malévola".

The first one doesn't make sense to me (does not sound natural nor seems to have a proper meaning).

The second sounds a little bit better (I would perfectly understand what you mean if you said that to me), but still I think is not what you would hear the most, for somebody who is happy about other people's misfortunes or bad luck. Probably is just a personal preference and bias.

Answer (score 0):

### It does not exist as a single word.

> What is the proper translation of the word "Epicaricacy"?

The first two words that you mentioned ("alegría maligna", "satisfacción malévola") are the correct ones.

> Is it one of those complex words that only have a meaning in the original language?

No. You can translate the word into Spanish without losing the original meaning, but not as a single word.

You may find "translations" of the word in some websites, but they are not recognized by the Royal Spanish Academy.

Also, a search in [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Epicaricacia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) (book search engine) of "epicaricacía" returned **0** results.